# Multiblog engine for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, blog-engine

I know, different forms of this questions were asked on this site multiple times, but I haven't seen a single answer that would satisfy my need.
I need a ASP.NET based blogging engine that wouul use SQL Server as a back end and allow multiple independet blogs in one app instance. I'm writing a community website for major bank and blogging is the piece I'm not sure about. 
Answers to other questions include a broad spectrum from BlogEngine.NET (doesn't support multiple blogs) to CommunityServer (a beast! blogging is just asmall piece of it). I don't want to install a full-blown CRM and just use blogging, I want a blogging engine. I don't mind to buy a commercial one but I can't find one.

I'm pretty much stuck, and any ideas are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider Oxite if you are confident in your markup and knowledge of html. Also, you can extend it with html editors to unsure better markup. I personally love how flexible the framework is.

Here is the [Oxite website](http://visitmix.com/labs/oxite/) with more info. BTW, it was used to build MIX online for Microsoft.